# How to kill the keyboard in Firefox OS Simulator

Tags: keyboard, simulator

I want to run some Firefox OS apps in my PC. So I'm using a [big-sized Firefox OS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31458965/1529630).

The problem is that the keyboard grows huge and covers too much space:

[image]

Since this is in fact running on my PC, I use the physical keyboard instead of the Firefox OS one.

So I don't want this keyboard. Is there a way to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the profile folder of Firefox:

   1. Go to `about:support`
   2. Find the "Application Basics" section
   3. Find the "Profile Folder" entry in the table
   4. Click the "Show Folder" button
2. Go to the `extensions` subfolder
3. Find the folder of your simulator, e.g. `fxos_2_2_simulator@mozilla.org`
4. Go to `b2g` subfolder
5. Go to `modules` subfolder
6. Open the `Keyboard.jsm` with a text editor.
7. Find the `_messageNames` array initializer:

   ```js
   _messageNames: [
     'RemoveFocus',
     'SetSelectionRange', 'ReplaceSurroundingText', 'ShowInputMethodPicker',
     'SwitchToNextInputMethod', 'HideInputMethod',
     'GetText', 'SendKey', 'GetContext',
     'SetComposition', 'EndComposition',
     'Register', 'Unregister'
   ],
   ```
8. Comment `'Register'`:

   ```js
   _messageNames: [
     'RemoveFocus',
     'SetSelectionRange', 'ReplaceSurroundingText', 'ShowInputMethodPicker',
     'SwitchToNextInputMethod', 'HideInputMethod',
     'GetText', 'SendKey', 'GetContext',
     'SetComposition', 'EndComposition',
     /*'Register',*/ 'Unregister'
   ],
   ```
9. Restart the Simulator (no need to restart Firefox)

Now focusing a text field won't open the keyboard, but you will be able to write with the physical one. Focusing a `select` will still display a dialog to choose some `option`.

If you want to disable the keyboard completely (including `select`), instead of `'Register'` scroll to the end of the file and comment this line:

```js
this.Keyboard.init();
```

[image]